# cocoon, nested can't create and remove

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, devise, cocoon-gem

In Rails 4 I want to create an order including product in a devise seller, I use gem "cocoon"

```
class Seller < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :orders

class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :seller
has_many :products
accepts_nested_attributes_for :products, allow_destroy: true

class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :order
```

and I want to create in new.html but the seller don't need to sign in, I hope it can via URL

```
 new.html
<%- model_class = Order -%>   
<%= simple_form_for @order, :html => { :class => 'form-horizontal' } do |f| %> 
<%= f.simple_fields_for :products do |product| %>
<%= render 'product_fields', :f => product %>
<% end %>
<%= link_to_add_association 'add product', f, :products %>
<%= f.button :submit, :class => 'btn-primary' %>
<% end %>

in product_fields

<%= f.input :name %>
<%= f.input :description %>
<%= link_to_remove_association 'remove product', f %>

def new
 current_seller = Seller.find{|person|person.store==params[:store]}
 @order = current_seller.orders.new
end

def create
@seller = current_seller
@order = @seller.orders.new(order_create_params)

respond_to do |format|
  if @order.save
    format.html { redirect_to @order, notice: 'Order was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @order }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @order.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

end
the URL like /orders/new?store=test03

```
def order_create_params
  params.require(:order).permit(products_attributes: [:id, :name, :description, :_destroy]).merge(:seller_id => @seller.id)
end
```

I tried a lots way to build but now "remove product" didn't work and If I use Order.new to create only the first one product can save in order(which displays in the beginning) and can't get seller_id and now will cause undefined method `orders' for nil:NilClass when I create

how can I def my create actioin to create order can link seller and add remove product can work

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `product_fields` partial needs to be surrounded with a `div` with class `nested-fields` for the remove to work.